# Two javascript delete function on same page

Tags: javascript

I have an area on my page for notes and another for tasks. Each have the option to delete an individual note or task.

I have two blocks of javascript to handle the deleting. One for the notes and the other for the tasks. However, when I attempt to delete a record from either the notes or the tasks it only fires one of the functions, the second one in the order.  So if I have the block of note delete code first and the task delete code second, the task delete code always fires if I attempt to delete a note or a task.  If I switch the blocks of code so the task delete code is first and the note delete code is second, then the note delete code fires.

I am using the SweetAlert2.js but that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Thanks,

JBishop

```
<!-- DELETE TASK -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#deleteTask', function (e) {

            var taskId = $(this).data('id');
            SwalDelete(taskId);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function SwalDelete(taskId) {

        swal({
            title: 'Delete this task?',
            text: 'There is no recovering from this.',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it',
            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success btn-fill",
            cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger btn-fill",
            buttonsStyling: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

            preConfirm: function () {
                return new Promise(function (resolve) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Firm/Methods/deleteTask.cshtml?TaskId=' + taskId,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    })
                        .done(function (response) {
                            swal('Boom!', 'Your task was deleted***!', 'success');
                            loadMatterInfo();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            swal('Oops...', 'Something went wrong!', 'error');
                        });
                });
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    }
</script>

<!-- DELETE NOTE -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#deleteNote', function (e) {

            var noteId = $(this).data('id');
            SwalDelete(noteId);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function SwalDelete(noteId) {

        swal({
            title: 'Delete this note?',
            text: 'There is no recovering from this.',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it',
            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-success btn-fill",
            cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-danger btn-fill",
            buttonsStyling: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

            preConfirm: function () {
                return new Promise(function (resolve) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Firm/Methods/deleteNote.cshtml?NoteId=' + noteId,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    })
                        .done(function (response) {
                            swal('Boom!', 'Your note was deleted###!', 'success');
                            loadMatterInfo();
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            swal('Oops...', 'Something went wrong!', 'error');
                        });
                });
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use a different function name or wrap it in a self calling closure `(function())();`

Comment: Different names is the real answer.  but you could simply put the code in the click event handlers, or (as above) wrap the 2 sections of script in enclosures so they have their own scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you have two separate `<script>` tags in your document and are naming the delete functions exactly the same?

From what I can see you are defining a function "SwalDelete" in your first script and then defining another function "SwalDelete" in your second script,  hiding the first definition.

I would suggest merging the two script tags and renaming the functions, for instance:

```
<script>
    function SwalDeleteTask(taskId) {
        ...
    }

    function SwalDeleteNote(noteId) {
        ...
    }

     $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '#deleteNote', function (e) {
            var noteId = $(this).data('id');
            SwalDeleteNote(noteId);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#deleteTask', function (e) {
            var taskId = $(this).data('id');
            SwalDeleteTask(taskId);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the two `<script>` tags belong to the same scope. Therefore, even if the two `SwalDelete` functions are contained in different `<script>` tags, in fact the second definition overrides the first one, causing the behavior you described.

There are three main solutions:

1. Give different names to the two functions.
2. Put the content of each of the two scripts in an IIFE

   ```
   (function () {
       // <script> tag content here
   })();
   ```
3. Put each function `SwalDelete` directly in the body of the event handler.

The 1st solution is to be preferred if you need to expose the functions in other places besides the event handlers, while the 2nd and the 3rd keeps the global scope cleaner. Moreover, all three solutions allow you to merge the two `<script>` tags together.